# How return multiple DataFrames by the functions in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a function that should return multiple DataFrames:

```
val df1, df2, df3 = getData(spark,df1,df2,df3)

def getData(spark: SparkSession, 
            path1: String, 
            path2: String,
            path3: String) : DataFrame = {

  val epoch = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000

  val df1 = spark.read.parquet(path1)
  val df2 = spark.read.parquet(path2)
  val df3 = spark.read.parquet(path3)

  df1, df2, df3
}
```

However, I get the compilation error that `df1, df2, df3` cannot be returned.

Comment: Shouldn't your return type be a tuple: `(DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either return the tuple or list of dataframe:

for example:
To send the tuple of dataframes

```
def getData(spark: SparkSession, 
            path1: String, 
            path2: String,
            path3: String) = {
//code
(df1, df2, df3)
}
```

To send the list of dataframes

```
def getData(spark: SparkSession, 
                path1: String, 
                path2: String,
                path3: String) = {
    //code
    List(df1, df2, df3)
    }
```

Comment: Could you please upvote my question. I do not think that it's useless.